Error 'Could not load certificate' when load a self-signed certificate into a Indy web server
I want to get a token from a desktop app that calls an OAuth2 authentication server that requires an HTTPS connection for the callback.
For this, I created a local Indy web server and use a self-signed SSL certificate created with Indy and OpenSSL after many discussions with ChatGPT - I have already been informed :) That's a great way to write bad code!
The error is:

raised exception class EIdOSSLLoadingCertError with message 'Could not load certificate. error:0D07209B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:too long'.

I assume that the certificate was not generated correctly
The app code is as follows:
type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    ...
    Memo1: TMemo;
    btnLoginANAF: TButton;
    RESTClient1: TRESTClient;
    RESTRequest1: TRESTRequest;
    RESTResponse1: TRESTResponse;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure Label1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnLoginANAFClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Label1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnLoginANAFClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FHTTPServer: TIdHTTPServer;
    FIOHandler: TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL;
    FAuthCode: string;
    procedure StartLocalServer;
    procedure StopLocalServer;
    procedure HandleRequest(AContext: TIdContext;
      ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
    function RequestAccessToken(AuthCode: string): Boolean;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

const
  ...

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

...

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FHTTPServer := TIdHTTPServer.Create(nil);
  if IdSSLOpenSSL.LoadOpenSSLLibrary then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('OpenSSL version: ' + IdSSLOpenSSL.OpenSSLVersion);
    Memo1.Lines.Add('');

    FIOHandler := TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.Create(FHTTPServer);
    FHTTPServer.IOHandler := FIOHandler;

    // Configurarea SSL
    FIOHandler.SSLOptions.CertFile := '.\CertificatTest.pem';
    FIOHandler.SSLOptions.KeyFile := '.\CheiePrivata.crt';
    // Același fișier ca CertFile
    FIOHandler.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := '';
    // Nu este necesar pentru certificat auto-semnat
    FIOHandler.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmServer;
    FIOHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
    FIOHandler.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
  end
  else
    raise Exception.Create(IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.WhichFailedToLoad());

  StartLocalServer;
end;

procedure TForm2.StartLocalServer;
begin
  FHTTPServer.DefaultPort := 8080;
  FHTTPServer.OnCommandGet := HandleRequest;
  FHTTPServer.Active := True; // <-- Error Here
end;

procedure TForm2.StopLocalServer;
begin
  FHTTPServer.Active := False;
  FHTTPServer.Free;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StopLocalServer;
end;

procedure TForm2.HandleRequest(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  Code: string;
begin
  if ARequestInfo.Document = '/callback' then
  begin
    Code := ARequestInfo.Params.Values['code'];
    if Code <> '' then
    begin
      FAuthCode := Code;
      AResponseInfo.ContentText :=
        'Successful authorization. You can close this window.';
      if RequestAccessToken(Code) then
      begin
        // Successful authorization. You can close this window.)
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Successful authorization. AuthCode=' + Code)
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      AResponseInfo.ContentText := 'Error: The authorization code was not received.';
    end;
  end
  else
  begin
    AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 404;
    AResponseInfo.ContentText := 'Page not found';
  end;
end;

function TForm2.RequestAccessToken(AuthCode: string): Boolean;
var
  Response: TJSONObject;
  AccessToken: string;
begin
  Result := False;
  RESTClient1.BaseURL := TOKEN_ENDPOINT;
  RESTRequest1.Method := rmPOST;
  RESTRequest1.Params.Clear;
  RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
  RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('code', AuthCode);
  RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('redirect_uri', REDIRECT_URI);
  RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('client_id', CLIENT_ID);
  RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('client_secret', CLIENT_SECRET);

  try
    RESTRequest1.Execute;
    if RESTResponse1.StatusCode = 200 then
    begin
      Response := RESTResponse1.JSONValue as TJSONObject;
      AccessToken := Response.GetValue('access_token').Value;
      // Save or use AccessToken as needed
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Acces token:');
      Memo1.Lines.Add(AccessToken);
      Result := True;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage('Error obtaining the access token: ' + E.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.Label1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
  procedure GenerateSelfSignedCertificate(const AFileName: string);
    procedure GenerateRandomSerialNumber(SerialNumber: PASN1_INTEGER);
    var
      RandomValue: Integer;
      I: Integer;
    begin
      RandomValue := 0;
      for I := 1 to 4 do
      begin
        RandomValue := (RandomValue shl 8) or Random(256);
      end;

      // We make sure that the number is positive
      RandomValue := RandomValue and $7FFFFFFF;

      // We set the serial number
      if ASN1_INTEGER_set(SerialNumber, RandomValue) = 0 then
        raise Exception.Create('Error setting the serial number');
    end;

    function DateToASN1_TIME(const ADate: TDateTime): PASN1_TIME;
    var
      AStruct: TSystemTime;
      ASN1_Time: PASN1_TIME;
    begin
      DateTimeToSystemTime(ADate, AStruct);
      ASN1_Time := ASN1_TIME_set(nil, SystemTimeToDateTime(AStruct));
      Result := ASN1_Time;
    end;

  var
    Cert: PX509;
    PrivateKey: PEVP_PKEY;
    SerialNumber: PASN1_INTEGER;
    Name: PX509_NAME;
    BioCert, BioKey: PBIO;
    NotBefore, NotAfter: TDateTime;
    LoadOpenSSLLibraryErr: string;
  begin
    // Create new certificate
    try 
      Cert := X509_new;
    except
      raise Exception.Create('Error creating certificate X509')
    end;

    try
      // New RSA Private Key Generation
      PrivateKey := EVP_PKEY_new;
      try
        if EVP_PKEY_assign(PrivateKey, EVP_PKEY_RSA,
          PByte(RSA_generate_key(2048, RSA_F4, nil, nil))) = 0 then
          raise Exception.Create('Error generating private key');

        // Certificate Version Setting (X509 v3)
        X509_set_version(Cert, 2);

        // Random Serial Number Generation
        SerialNumber := ASN1_INTEGER_new;
        if SerialNumber = nil then
          raise Exception.Create('Error creating ASN1_INTEGER');

        try
          GenerateRandomSerialNumber(SerialNumber);
          if X509_set_serialNumber(Cert, SerialNumber) = 0 then
            raise Exception.Create
              ('Error setting the serial number for the certificate');
        finally
          ASN1_INTEGER_free(SerialNumber);
        end;

        // Set the start and end date of the certificate
        NotBefore := Now - 1; // The certificate is valid from yesterday
        NotAfter := NotBefore + 364; // The certificate is valid for one year
        X509_set_notBefore(Cert, DateToASN1_TIME(NotBefore));
        X509_set_notAfter(Cert, DateToASN1_TIME(NotAfter));

        // Public Key Setting
        X509_set_pubkey(Cert, PrivateKey);

        // Setting Issuer and Subject Name (localhost)
        Name := X509_get_subject_name(Cert);
        X509_NAME_add_entry_by_txt(Name, 'CN', MBSTRING_ASC,
          PAnsiChar('localhost'), -1, -1, 0);
        X509_set_issuer_name(Cert, Name);

        // Certificate Signing
        if X509_sign(Cert, PrivateKey, EVP_sha256) = 0 then
          raise Exception.Create('Error signing the certificate');

        // Save certificate to PEM file
        BioCert := BIO_new_file(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(AFileNamePem)), 'w+');
        try
          if PEM_write_bio_X509(BioCert, Cert) = 0 then
            raise Exception.Create
              ('Error saving certificate to PEM file');
        finally
          BIO_free(BioCert);
        end;

        // Save Private Key to CRT File
        BioKey := BIO_new_file(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(AFileNameCrt)), 'w+');
        try
          if PEM_write_bio_PrivateKey(BioKey, PrivateKey, nil, nil, 0, nil,
            nil) = 0 then
            raise Exception.Create
              ('Error saving private key to CRT file');
        finally
          BIO_free(BioKey);
        end;

      finally
        EVP_PKEY_free(PrivateKey);
      end;
    finally
      X509_free(Cert);
    end;
  end;

begin
  GenerateSelfSignedCertificate('.\CertificatTest.pem', '.\CheiePrivata.crt');
  ShowMessage('Certificate and private key successfully generated!');
end;

procedure TForm2.btnLoginANAFClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  URL: string;
begin
  URL := AUTH_ENDPOINT + '?response_type=code' + '&client_id=' +
    TNetEncoding.URL.Encode(CLIENT_ID) + '&redirect_uri=' +
    TNetEncoding.URL.Encode(REDIRECT_URI) + '&scope=' +
    TNetEncoding.URL.Encode(SCOPE);

  ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar(URL), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;

...

Initialization

Randomize;
IdOpenSSLSetLibPath(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName));

end.


"For this, I ... use a self-signed SSL certificate created with Indy and OpenSSL" - which version of OpenSSL did you use to create the certificate?

Open SSL 1.0.2u

In my computer I have two OpenSSL versions installed. How I can check what version was load?

preferably you should have the desired version in your app's folder. You can also tell Indy which folder to load the OpenSSL libs from by calling IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.IdOpenSSLSetLibPath() at app startup. But, in any case, to see the loaded version, you can call IdSSLOpenSSL.OpenSSLVersion() after OpenSSL is loaded.

In the Initialization section I have now:
IdOpenSSLSetLibPath(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)); In code the function IdSSLOpenSSL.OpenSSLVersion() return: OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2u  20 Dec 2019. Error remain the same
